# Implementing search for a view

Tags: views, users, database, search

I have a view containing objects of a custom content type. Could anyone please tell me how I could allow my users to search only objects that have certain attributes? Some sort of like "Show me objects that are located in X, have a size of Y and colour Z".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and expose filter in the view. This is not a full blown search but might be sufficient for your needs. If you need more advanced functionality, try [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).

Comment: Exposed a filter for the field I wanted to be searched. Good thinking.